# How to create .der file in golang same as openssl do

Tags: go, openssl, cryptography

"openssl rsa -in prevate.pem -outform DER -pubout -out public.der"

Comment: What is the input format of the key? PEM?

Comment: It is PEM file, I am using preivate.pem file

Comment: Actually, the OpenSSL statement extracts the _public_ X.509 DER encoded key from a _private_ PKCS#8 PEM encoded key. This can be achieved with the functions `ParsePKCS8PrivateKey()` and `MarshalPKIXPublicKey()` from the X509 package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider a library like [`google/trillian`](https://github.com/google/trillian), which does include a [`MustMarshalPublicPEMToDER(keyPEM string) []byte`](https://github.com/google/trillian/blob/57e4a52d22ef65805363b8e6bea4089a72003c62/crypto/keys/testonly/keys.go#L36-L50) function.

```golang
// MustMarshalPublicPEMToDER reads a PEM-encoded public key and returns it in DER encoding.
// If an error occurs, it panics.
func MustMarshalPublicPEMToDER(keyPEM string) []byte {
    block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(keyPEM))
    key, err := x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    keyDER, err := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return keyDER
}
```

As the comment of this function shows, this reads a PEM-encoded public key.

As noted by [Topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco), you would need [`crypto/x509#ParsePKCS8PrivateKey`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509#ParsePKCS8PrivateKey) in order to read a private PKCS#8 PEM encoded key.
The marshal part does not change.